# Youtube API, iOS. Get items from 2 playlist

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have playlist A and playlist B.

Can I request for items from A and B in one request? I need to get mix of this playlists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an other example where checking the documentation will help

[PlayLists.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list)

> id    string
>  The id parameter specifies a comma-separated list of the
>   YouTube playlist ID(s) for the resource(s) that are being retrieved.
>   In a playlist resource, the id property specifies the playlist's
>   YouTube playlist ID.

you can send more then one play list id you just need to separate them with a comma.  Use the try me at the bottom of the page to test it.